# Magento Authorize.net test mode

Tags: authorize.net

We have a site that was in Authorize.net test mode.  An order happened to go through during this time, is there anyway to resend that order, i.e. cancel & reorder...etc?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is Magento 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Best way I can think of is to cancel and reoder (you may need to contact the customer to get there credit call info)

> Test Mode allows you to test your connection to the payment gateway
>   without actually authorizing or charging real credit cards or bank
>   accounts. Transactions submitted while your account is in Test Mode
>   are not stored by the payment gateway and will not be viewable in
>   search results or reports.
>
> After initial setup, your payment gateway account is placed in Test Mode by default. This allows you to immediately test your
>   connection to the payment gateway before you submit real transactions.
>   However, you may turn Test Mode on or off any time you need to test
>   changes to your payment gateway connection or to restore live
>   transaction processing.

Read more https://www.authorize.net/support/CP/helpfiles/Account/Settings/Security_Settings/General_Settings/Test_Mode.htm